# Flux of the vector field through the surface of a sphere?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, spheres

Find the flux of the vector field $F=(x^3, y^3, z^3)$ through the surface of a sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=x$

Can someone please show me how to calculate this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can never remember if it is Gauss, Green or Stokes, but one of them has a theorem that might help you.

Comment: What is the radius of your sphere?

Comment: I would say the radius is r=1/2. At least after my calculation

Comment: The radius should be given information.   Or, if it isn't then we can just call it R.

Comment: Ok, it wasn't given in the problem. But we got shown how to calculate it during the lecture and came to r=1/2

Comment: Your statement of the equation of the surface of the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ doesn't mean anything.  You should have $x^2+y^2 + z^2 = r^2$

Comment: $x^2+y^2+z^2=x$

Answer (score 2):

Since a sphere is closed, I would suggest applying the divergence theorem.

$\iint F(x,y,z)\cdot dS = \iiint \nabla\cdot F dV$

$\nabla\cdot F = 3x^2 + 3y^2 + 3 z^2$

Convert to spherical coordinates.

$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^R 3\rho^2(\rho^2\sin\phi) dV$

$\frac {12}{5}\pi R^5$

If you don't want to use Gauss's / divergence theorem.

Again convert to spherical.

$x = R\cos\theta\sin\phi\\
y = R\sin\theta\sin\phi\\
z = R\cos\phi$

$dS = ( \frac {\partial x}{\partial\theta}, \frac {\partial y}{ \partial \theta},\frac {\partial z}{\partial \theta})\times (\frac {\partial x}{\partial \phi}, \frac {\partial y}{\partial \phi},\frac {\partial z}{\partial \phi})$

Comment: Thank you very much!! This helps me a lot. When I used the Gauss's theorem, I also got a similiar solution. But I calculated it with the radius 1/2, so it's slightly different.

Comment: Could you show me how to calculate it without using the divergence theorem and by using the radius r=1/2?